# Divide and calculate on grids

Tags: c++, grid

My C++ program involves numerous mathematical calculations from a sphere of diameter Xnm. Where is size of sphere is declared as below.

```
p->a.ld(1, 2000.); //%diameter of sphere

    where ld is 
// ******operator ld load

void ld (long r,long c, float w) 
{   
    #ifdef CHECKBOUND
        if (r>rows || c>cols || r<1 || c<1)
        {
            ERR(); // ERR
            std::cout << "** Invalid Element";
            return ;
        }
    #endif
    arr[FLATTEN2(r,c)]=w;
    return ;
};
```

I would like to split the sphere into parts(2 or 4) for calculation, and send each part to different computers or grids for the calculation and collect the results back! This part seems challenging for me. I hope someone has already overcome this problem and would like to share some idea how to do this!
Since I am planning to use other complex structures instead of sphere I may have to split them into even more parts and there will be varying parameters also and I need to collect the results back and produce the final results.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: look into map/reduce algorithms.